# Add android.permission.CAMERA with Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, permissions, camera

I am using the latest version of Cordova (6.3.1) and I want the following permission to appear in the AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Adding this line by hand does not work because the XML is regenerated each time I run the command `cordova run android`

I have added the `cordova-plugin-camera` to my project with

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
```

This plugin does NOT add the CAMERA permission in the AndroidManifest.xml

I don't know if this is normal

How can I add this permission to my project ?

---

**Edit :**
Usually, Cordova plugins are in charge of adding required permissions into the manifest. The camera plugin does not add this specific permission, I wonder :

- if the plugin should add this permission (bug ? I have opened an issue on their Jira tracker)
- if I can add this permission by hand myself, maybe in the Cordova's config.xml

Comment: do you any error in console ?

Comment: No error in console. The permission is just not present in the manifest.

Comment: Please remove and reinstall your camera plugin.Then check your manifist file .Thanks

Comment: @HassanALi I just tried that and the CAMERA permission did not appear in the manifest :(

Comment: if you manually add this permission ,Isn't it works ?

Comment: Just tell me how to add it. As I say in my question, if I add the permission directly in the manifest, it goes away when I build my app, because the build command overwrites the manifest file.

Answer (score 17):

I don't think the Camera plugin ever added this permission to `AndroidManifest.xml`. Looking through the Github repo, `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` was added in June 2013 (CB-3654), but I don't see anything for the camera itself. Not sure why that would be, but you can either add the permission to `AndroidManifest.xml` yourself or add a `config-file` directive in your project's `config.xml` file, for example:

```
    <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*" mode="merge">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    </config-file>
```

Comment: I had to add `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` to the root `widget` tag in the `config.xml` to get it work.

Answer (score -10):

Are you building native or hybrid app?

For native you can refer this website:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

Comment: Cordova is a tool to build hybrid app, I am using Cordova CLI to build my app

Comment: FYI: it is framework and if you need to change permission for android you can do that in config file.